# Linux installation on Proliant DL360 G7

Tags: ubuntu, debian, fedora, hp-proliant

I'm trying to install Linux (any distribution) on a Proliant DL360 G7 using iLO3 (I don't have a monitor to connect to the server).
The server specification are: HPE PROLIANT DL360 G7 E5620 1P 4GB-R SFF SAS.

I succeded the first time with a virtual drive configured on iLO, using the ISO image of Ubuntu saved on my MAC, everything was ok so I decided to install the OS on the Hard Disk of the server using a bootable USB key, but I couldn't.
I've tried installing Ubuntu, Red Hat, Debian and Fedora, the result is the same.

I can go throught the installation process (using graphical interface too), the process ends with the installation process asking me to remove the USB drive and restart.
The machine restarts, the Ubuntu (or another OS) logo appears but when the GUI must appears the server hangs and I can see just the arrow of the mouse on the screen.

I tried with:

- debian-12.5.0-amd64
- rhel-9.3-x86_64
- FC-5-x86_64
- Ubuntu 24.04

E.g. with Fedora I can see the Fedora logo and then the server hangs.
[Fedora starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iMLt.png)
[Server hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifPQF.png)

With all the OSs the result is the same, the OS starts, I can see the logo and then the server hangs (I can see the arrow of the mouse but nothing happen, and the arrow doesn't move).
After the server get hung I can connect ssh to the server anyway, that means that the server is working, it seems like something happen with remote console or graphic interface.

I also tried to install Debian without GUI, and everything worked fine. I could use the shell and do averything (install packages and so on).
As soon as I tried to install Gnome, the server started the Gnome GUI and hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to diagnose the exact problem, I would just suggest **not installing a GUI** on those servers. They have only the *absolute bare minimum* graphics adapter (not even an 'iGPU', really), generally something MGA200-like that is integrated into the iLO remote KVM feature, and they will not run anything that requires 3D acceleration. (Until recently, the Linux drivers for these chips only supported the legacy framebuffer mode, not even modern DRI.)

So although you can have *some* Linux GUIs running (much like Windows can show a GUI), it would be more along the lines of **Xfce at most** – definitely not the GPU-intensive GNOME Shell that you're trying to start on Fedora.

As far as server management goes, a standard Debian or Fedora GUI won't even help you much, anyway: most distros (except perhaps SuSE) don't have any "mmc.exe"-like tools for local server configuration. Any setup you do would be either through a text editor (which is going to be much more convenient to do via SSH/SFTP than via iLO), or through a web-based tool like Cockpit or Webmin. (Cockpit is a RHEL/Fedora thing and might even be offered during install.)

Comment: Thanks @u1686_grawity, I'll try with Xfce. I need a GUI because I want to install android-studio (I'd like to create an android-studio server letting me to develop app on Android via iLO remote desktop). The wierd thing is that the first Ubuntu installation on iLO Virtual Drive succeded, I've never succeeded since then

Comment: @GiorgioTorassa: That might work, but you'll still have better luck with running the Xfce GUI via VNC (or via RDP, or Xpra, or NX if that's still a thing). Although VNC still doesn't magically make GPU-heavy environments work without a GPU, it still gives better experience than iLO KVM.

Comment: Tried with Xfce, it worked! You saved me, @u1686_grawity. Thanks a lot